# How to move folders if they contain a certain file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, batch-processing

I'm writing some (ugly) code in batch to rearrange files between folders.

I've created a part of the code that moves file of one type with similar filenames to the same folder, and creates a dummy text file called "serie.txt", if there is more than a file in it.

At the end, I have a folder called "E:\videos\catalogar\" with lots of subfolders, and some of them contain the file "series.txt". I need to move these folders to the path "e:\videos\series\", and, for this, I wrote this:

```
for /r "e:\videos\catalogar\" %%F in (serie.txt) do (
   set directorio=%%~dpF
   if not "!directorio!"=="e:\videos\catalogar\" (
    del "!directorio!*.txt"
    move /y "!directorio!." "e:\videos\series\"
   )
)
```

`delayedexpansion` is turned on. The `if` condition is to avoid moving the entire root folder.

The problem is that, for some reason, this code moves **all** subfolders inside "E:\videos\catalogar\", not only the ones that contain "serie.txt". What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /r "e:\videos\catalogar\" %%F in (serie.txt) do (
```

executes a directory-scan, but does **not** use the filemask. It will only use the filemask if the filemask contains `*` or `?`. Personally, I believe that's a bug (OK if the filemask is `'.'` but should-match-mask-regardless otherwise) and perhaps asking Microsoft to fix it for W10 [here may work.](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt/filters/new)

So - maybe add the gate as suggested, or include `*` or `?` in the filemask to force "only directories matching" would solve your problem.

Either way, there's little point in assigning a value to `directorio` as `%%~dpF` will have exactly the same effect in the sniplet posted.

Comment: Thank you, mate, this works for me! I've used the "seri?.txt" mask and I deleted also the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

`for /r` walks a directory tree, and you aren't testing for the existance of `serie.txt` in the subfolders, so yout script is trying every folder and every folder except the root.

A script like this would try one level of subfolders and test for dummy files in those folders:

```
for /d %f in ("e:\videos\catalogar\*") do (
    if exist "%%f\serie.txt" (
        move ...
```